# how I can use Haml file for making a static website?

Tags: windows, compiler-construction, haml

I want to write html pages that  I need to write in haml format  (I want this because someone want me to made design in haml format that they can use in their dynamic website).  Do someone know anything that I can use to write haml on windows computer.

I need something that make me able to see the code worked on browser. I means a compiler in editor or something that is easy to do haml to html.

I have installed Nodejs in my computer and used it work on Jade and Ejs but nothing of those thing relate to my question. Do someone have idea if I can compile haml in nodejs. I heve heared from people that they compile their coffeescript In nodejs. Do someone know if nodejs have something that make me able to compile my haml in anyway.

I just want to write haml and want to get html that I can simply run locally in my browser.

Comment: What about `haml input.haml output.html`? http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#using_haml

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://middlemanapp.com/ to create your site using Haml and Scss. You can also compile it down to static html/css. Great tool!